# Assiging a number to a module

Tags: bash, shell

I need to be able to assign a number to a module, my current code is below. Gap is where it needs to be assigned.

```
assignmodules(){
#Assign first module
x=1
modules=$(ls ./modules)
for module in modules; do
   
  echo "$module assigned to slot $x"
  x=$(x+1)
done
}
```

A few things:
Module title has to be printed in a different function, so i cant print it within the for loop.
Module needs to be run this way:

```
case $choice in 
1) module1
2) module2
3) module3
etc.
```

Needs to be printed as following (If i find a good a solution that doesn't do it right, ill probably still use that.):

```
[1] Module1 [2] Module2
[3] Module3 [4] Module4
etc.
```

I tried this in the blank:
[{x}]module=$module
(i don't think this is exactly what i tried, i believe it was slightly different but i cant remember)
I wanted it to do as described above, but i don't think it will.

Comment: `modules=( modules/* ); modules=( "${modules[@]##*/}" )` is a better way to do that -- no `ls` needed at all. And it automatically assigns numbers: `for module_idx in "${!modules[@]}"; do echo "Module number $module_idx is ${modules[$module_idx]}"; done`

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: You sure you're using Bash?

Comment: (Oh -- the reason `x=$(x+1)` didn't work is that to get into an arithmetic context you need double parens: `x=$((x+1))`, or `((++x))`, or so forth)

Comment: im using bash but havent done bash in a while so it might look like python

Comment: Do you need that *exact* output, or just a menu that associates each module with a number? Look at the `select` statement in `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bash, just use an array and some globbing and special parameter expansion.

```
assignmodules() {
    set -- ./modules/*
    modules=(0 "${@/#./modules/}")
    unset 'modules[0]'
    declare -p modules # Optionally show result
}
```

Somewhere you can print the modules list using

```
for i in "${!modules[@]}"; do
    echo "[$i] ${modules[i]}"
done
```

Or

```
for i in "${!modules[@]}"; do
    echo -n "[$i] ${modules[i]} "
    (( i % 2 == 0 )) && echo
done

(( i % 2 )) && echo
```

It's also recommended to add `shopt -s nullglob` at the beginning of the script, especially if
modules directory can sometimes be empty.

Lastly, if you're wanting to ask user for choices, look at the `select` command. You may not need to display them manually.  Run `help select`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your modules in an array: Numerically-indexed arrays (the default kind) have indices that are numbered by nature (note that these numbers start at 0, not 1).

```
assignmodules() {
  declare -ga modules            # explicitly declare global array (optional)
  modules=( modules/* )          # put all modules directory entries in an array
  modules=( "${modules[@]#*/}" ) # strip modules/ prefix off each entry
}

assignmodules                    # calling that function leaves modules assigned

# to print your list of modules in the specific format requested might look like:
print_args=( )                            # generate format string argument array
for modules_idx in "${!modules[@]}"; do   # iterate over indices in array
  module=${modules[$module_idx]}          # retrieve corresponding module name
  print_args+=( "[$module_idx]" "$module" ) # append to list of stuff to print
done

# format string is repeated until all arguments are consumed
# so this way we get two columns as you requested
printf '%s %s\t%s %s\n' "${print_args[@]}" # actually print our list
```